# Can a /n/ turn into /r̃/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I think I heard a nasalized alveolar trill /r̃/ instead of alveolar nasal stop /n/ for the mora *na* in this video https://youtu.be/LIqnhSpXgtI?t=801 (13:26).
Am I correct?

(Whatever the phone is, is the allophone/variation more of an idiolect or more of a dialect?)

Comment: It sounds like <del>cyberpunk</del><ins>audio glitch</ins>.

Comment: The symbol is not rendered @brokenlaptop

Comment: Just sounds like phlegm to me. If you'll notice, the same sound happens two more times at 13:27-29 when he says ですか**ら** ここ**は**

Comment: @5ru8ek No, but it's okay since it's a joke. By the way, I pretty much believe that it's a glitch because I've experienced it a lot in Zoom meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, this odd sound you hear at the 13:26 mark is not a phoneme, but either phlegm in the speaker's throat, or an audio glitch or other artifact from digitization.

In this specific instance, it's relevant to point out that trilling one's "r"s is generally considered informal, sometimes even vulgar.  This video is of a professor discussing the grammar of Classical Japanese -- an extremely unlikely social context for trilled pronunciation.

Although I could imagine //ɴ// (moraic "n", i.e. ん) before //ɾ// (the tap or flap, as in らりるれろ) possibly parsing out as causing nasalization on the following //ɾ//, the [[r̃]] itself would not be considered any kind of allophone or alteration of //ɴ// -- the //ɴ// would still be there for listeners, both moraically and in the nasalization it causes on the preceding vowel (and sometimes also on the following phone).

There are no circumstances I've ever heard or read about where //n//, especially mora-initial //n-// as in the video, would ever be rendered as a trill of any sort.